# Increase the number of messages read by a Kafka consumer in a single poll

Tags: apache-kafka

Kafka consumer has a configuration `max.poll.records` which controls the maximum number of records returned in a single call to poll() and its [default value is 500](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#max.poll.records). I have set it to a very high number so that I can get all the messages in a single poll.
However, the poll returns only a few thousand messages(roughly 6000) in a single call even though the topic has many more. 
 How can I further increase the number of messages read by a single consumer?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Most probably your payload is limited by `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, which is 1MB by default. Refer to [Kafka Consumer configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#newconsumerconfigs).

Here's good detailed explanation:

> MAX.PARTITION.FETCH.BYTES
>
> This property controls the maximum number of bytes the server will return per partition. The default is 1 MB, which means that when KafkaConsumer.poll() returns ConsumerRecords, the record object will use at most max.partition.fetch.bytes per partition assigned to the consumer. So if a topic has 20 partitions, and you have 5 consumers, each consumer will need to have 4 MB of memory available for ConsumerRecords. In practice, you will want to allocate more memory as each consumer will need to handle more partitions if other consumers in the group fail. max. partition.fetch.bytes must be larger than the largest message a broker will accept (determined by the max.message.size property in the broker configuration), or the broker may have messages that the consumer will be unable to consume, in which case the consumer will hang trying to read them. Another important consideration when setting max.partition.fetch.bytes is the amount of time it takes the consumer to process data. As you recall, the consumer must call poll() frequently enough to avoid session timeout and subsequent rebalance. If the amount of data a single poll() returns is very large, it may take the consumer longer to process, which means it will not get to the next iteration of the poll loop in time to avoid a session timeout. If this occurs, the two options are either to lower max. partition.fetch.bytes or to increase the session timeout.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Increasing `max.partition.fetch.bytes` increased payload consumption and it was proportional as well. Thanks.

Comment: I am facing similar kind of issue, configured the `max.poll.records=20000` and `fetch.max.bytes=102428800`. There are already 15k messages in each partitions of the topic.(total 6 partitions). But still each poll is returning <= 6 messages in a batch.

Answer (score 47):

You can increase Consumer `poll()` batch size by increasing `max.partition.fetch.bytes`, but still as per documentation it has limitation with `fetch.max.bytes` which also need to be increased with required batch size. And also from the documentation there is one other property `message.max.bytes` in [Topic config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs) and [Broker config](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#brokerconfigs) to restrict the batch size. so one way is to increase all of these property based on your required batch size

In `Consumer config` **max.partition.fetch.bytes** default value is `1048576`

> The maximum amount of data per-partition the server will return. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer. If the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this limit, the batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. **The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config). See fetch.max.bytes for limiting the consumer request size**

In `Consumer Config` **fetch.max.bytes** default value is `52428800`

> The maximum amount of data the server should return for a fetch request. Records are fetched in batches by the consumer, and if the first record batch in the first non-empty partition of the fetch is larger than this value, the record batch will still be returned to ensure that the consumer can make progress. As such, this is not a absolute maximum. **The maximum record batch size accepted by the broker is defined via message.max.bytes (broker config) or max.message.bytes (topic config).** Note that the consumer performs multiple fetches in parallel.

In `Broker config` **message.max.bytes** default value is `1000012`

> **The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka.** If this is increased and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the consumers' fetch size must also be increased so that the they can fetch record batches this large.
>
> In the latest message format version, records are always grouped into batches for efficiency. In previous message format versions, uncompressed records are not grouped into batches and this limit only applies to a single record in that case.
>
> This can be set per topic with the topic level max.message.bytes config.

In `Topic config` **max.message.bytes** default value is `1000012`

> **The largest record batch size allowed by Kafka.** If this is increased and there are consumers older than 0.10.2, the consumers' fetch size must also be increased so that the they can fetch record batches this large.
>
> In the latest message format version, records are always grouped into batches for efficiency. In previous message format versions, uncompressed records are not grouped into batches and this limit only applies to a single record in that case.

Comment: @BdEngineer I'm also learning, if i understand it correctly, each broker will have multiple topics partitions, for example (broker 1 can have topic 1 -> partition 1 and partition 2, topic 2 -> partition 3 and partition 4), so i believe `message.max.bytes` is controlling batch per topic and batch per broker

Comment: what do you mean `consumer is pretty slow`? what are you doing with that data? probably i would suggest to ask a question with proper input and output details @BdEngineer

Comment: So I guess what happens if you set `max.partition.fetch.bytes` higher than `max.fetch.bytes`? Do you need to change both of these?

Comment: I haven't tried that combo, but still batch size might be limited to `max.fetch.bytes` taking it as precedence @alex

Comment: sorry I meant to type `fetch.max.bytes` referring to `ConsumerConfig.FETCH_MAX_BYTES_CONFIG`. Too late to edit my comment. Interesting I'll see if I can find something on it.