# behavior of kafka consumer poll method with one time call

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Let's say I call `poll()` just once with some timeout, instead of `while(true) {...poll...}`

1. Will the consumer get all the records from last committed to the latest available in one shot?
2. Does the timeout parameter matters? E.g. if `timeout==0` and there are millions of records, what happens?

Comment: According to my experiment, the poll behavior is kind of undefined.

(1) Using while(true) {...poll...}, the num of records per poll seems random to me
(2) I didn't find a relationship between timeout and number of records per poll either. But definitely it doesn't guarantee getting all available records at one shot

Please if someone can explain

Comment: This post has probably the best explanation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753883/increase-the-number-of-messages-read-by-a-kafka-consumer-in-a-single-poll

Answer (score 1):

According to the [kafka-doc](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs), by default `max.poll.records` is `500`

> The maximum number of records returned in a single call to `poll()`.

Therefore, every time you call `poll()` you can get upto `500` `max.poll.records=500` from last committed `offset`

Comment: It also says "By default, there is essentially no limit." https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html

Comment: @hawkssss No limit means that you can set this configuration up to any `int` but it defaults to `500`. I'll update my answer to include this. Hope this helps.

Comment: well I just experimented it with default, sometimes it gets more than 500 records in one poll...