# Set polling rate for kafka consumers per topic using springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

Is it possible to set different poll rates for consumers each kafka topics on SpringBoot? I would like to have one topic to be polling with longer intervals (like 5 minutes). I was hoping to use this to implement a retry for failed processing of messages from kafka.

A sample implementation will greatly help.

Comment: Refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51753883/increase-the-number-of-messages-read-by-a-kafka-consumer-in-a-single-poll

Comment: @Arun thanks for the response. But I wanted to change the interval between polling and not change the number of messages retrieved for every poll of the consumer, I updated my question to make it clearer.

Comment: you can do it, create different consumers for each topic @itabangay

Comment: @deadpool can you point me to a sample implementation on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 2.3, the listener container has a new property `idleBetweenPolls`. The container will ensure that the time between polls is no larger than `max.poll.interval.ms - 5000`.

You can set it for specific consumers using a container customizer bean...

```java
@Component
class Customizer {

    public Customizer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> factory, DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<?, ?> pf) {
        factory.setContainerCustomizer(container -> {
            if (container.getContainerProperties().getGroupId().equals("slowGroup")) {
                // or you can use the topic(s)
                container.getContainerProperties().setIdleBetweenPolls(60_000);
            }
        });
    }

}
```